# How to reinstall Grub on Ubuntu 20.04 installed on external hard disk

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, boot-repair, grub-efi

I had Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 installed on UEFI mode on my pc. I tried to install ubuntu 20.04 to my separate external hard disk connecting it to my pc which already had win10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

After the 'successful' in installation the grub of my internal hard disk broke. It shows grub>

If I connect the external hard disk it again works fine. I can also boot to windows by choosing it from boot options menu. 
My ubuntu root partition is on sda6
efi partition on /sda1

Thanks

Comment: You have to partition in advance & have ESP - efi system partition on external drive. But Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub to first drive, usually internal drive. You can disconnect or in UEFI settings temporarily disable internal drive. Or use this work around. (Please add to bug report). Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Ubuntu Installer uses wrong bootloader location for USB/sdb UEFI installs 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1173457

Answer (score -1):

You can use repair boot, it has an option call : "boot reinstall" and it use a graphical interface or you can use command line using grub wiki